# How to use CherrPy as Web server and Bottle as Application to support multiple virtual hosts?

Tags: python, virtualhost, cherrypy, bottle

I have a website (which running in Amazon EC2 Instance) running Python Bottle application with CherryPy as its front end web server.

Now I need to add another website with a different domain name already registered. To reduce the cost, I want to utilize the existing website host to do that.

Obviously, virtual host is the solution.

I know Apache mod_wsgi could play the trick. But I don't want to replace CherryPy.

I've googled a a lot, there are some articles showing how to make virtual hosts on CherryPy, but they all assume Cherrypy as Web Sever + Web application, Not CherrPy as Web server and Bottle as Application.

How to use CherrPy as Web server and Bottle as Application to support multiple virtual hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, use [VirtualHost](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cpwsgi.html?highlight=vhost#cherrypy._cpwsgi.VirtualHost). In the example `cherrypy.Application` instances are used, but any WSGI callable (e. g. Bottle app) will do.

Comment: Could you give me a simple sample? It seems Bootle App could not be directly used, after all, its not a cherrypy.Application.

Comment: I've never used Bottle, so this is untested. Since you need multiple Bottle instances, you create them with app1 = Bottle() app2 = Bottle(). Then route with @app1.route() @app2.route(). Finally vhost = VirtualHost(None, domains={'www.domain2.example': app1, 'www.domain2.example:443': app2,}) etc. Or put any app for None to make it a default one.

Comment: Yes, I finally got it done as you suggested. Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can simply put nginx as reverse proxy and configure it to send the traffic to the two domains to the right upstream (the cherryPy webserver).

Comment: I got it work by Cherrypy itself without any new module introduced. Any way, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to use Nginx (http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) with uWsgi(http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) & (uWsgi-python) plug-in

uWsgi has a module named emperor that you can link vhosts(vassals) in, sort of.

i'm a newbie at this myself, so not necessarily an answer but rather a suggestion to check it out.
just a heads up, uWsgi and Nginx can be a hassle to get it to work, depending on your linux distro. Does work nicely with bottle, tested it myself.
hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that site has served for pretty long time, I don't want to introduce new modules and take more effort to test them

Answer (score 0):

jwalker's answer is pretty clear. In case any CherryPy newbie need whole script for reference, I post one below.

```
import cherrypy
from bottle import Bottle
import os


app1 = Bottle() 
app2 = Bottle()

@app1.route('/')
def homePage():    
    return "=========  home1 ==============="


@app2.route('/')
def homePage_2():    
    return "=========  home2 ==============="

vhost = cherrypy._cpwsgi.VirtualHost(None, 
                                     domains={
                                              'www.domain1.com': app1, 
                                              'www.domain2.com': app2,
                                             }
                                     )

cherrypy.tree.graft(vhost) 

cherrypy.config.update({
                        'server.socket_host': '192.168.1.4',
                        'server.socket_port': 80,
                      })
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

you could make www.domain1.com and www.domain1.com point to one IP adress of you server, so it servers for 2 domain in one Web Server.